# Call method in different controller in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, callback, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller from where I will be showing a window controller using [runmodal]. I have some textfields  and button in the modal window. When i click the button i need to call a method in view controller with the collective data from window controller. How can i achieve this? Is there anything to do with custom delegate method? As I am new to Mac dev and objective c some one help me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the delegation pattern. You define a protocol like this:

```
@protocol DataProviderDelegate <NSObject>
- (NSDictionary *) retrieveData;
@end
```

implement this protocol in your view controller:

```
@interface MainViewController () <DataProviderDelegate>
@end

@implementation MainViewController {
...
- (NSDictionary *) retrieveData {
    ....
}

...
@end
```

In your window controller you define a delegate property

```
@interface ModalWindowController : NSWindowController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DataProviderDelegate> dataProviderDelegate;

@end
```

From the main view controller, set that property to self

```
modalWindow.dataProviderDelegate = self
```

At this point the modal window controller is able to call any method of the view controller that is defined in the `DataProviderDelegate` protocol - for instance:

```
if (self.dataProviderDelegate) {
    [self.dataProviderDelegate retrieveData];
}
```

To dig more in the *delegation pattern* I suggest to google for it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate for this. In the ModalViewController you will have to implement a delegate that will have a method per action (textfields, buttons) :

**ModalViewController.h**

```
@class ModalViewController;

@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)modalViewControllerDelegateButtonPressed:(APPCameraOverlay *)overlay;
- (void)modalViewControllerDelegate:(APPCameraOverlay *)overlay
                    textFieldEdited:(NSString *)text;

@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then, you will be able to call your delegate methods inside your ModalViewController.m :

**ModalViewController.m**

```
// The method linked to your button
- (IBAction)actionButtonPressed {
    [self.delegate modalViewControllerDelegateButtonPressed:self];
}

// Your textfield method that is called when input has changed
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.delegate modalViewControllerDelegate:self
                               textFieldEdited:textField.text];
}
```

Now, you just have to set your ModalViewController delegate object in the ViewController when showing the modal controller :

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ModalViewController.h"

// We create an extension to the class to implement the delegate protocol
@interface ViewController () <ModalViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

// This method gets called by apple when a view controller is showed (modally, pushed or embedded)
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // if the view that is showed is the ModalViewController
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ModalViewController class]]) {
        ModalViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    }    
}

// You have to implement the delegate methods now :

- (void)modalViewControllerDelegateButtonPressed:(APPCameraOverlay *)overlay {
    // Do whatever you want when the button is pressed on the ModalViewController
}

- (void)modalViewControllerDelegate:(APPCameraOverlay *)overlay
                    textFieldEdited:(NSString *)text {
    // Do whatever you want when the textfield is edited
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the view controller as an instance variable to your (subclassed) window controller, and then when the button is clicked you can send a method to the view controller with the collective data from the window controller.